# Trouble in Batch using quotes in a variable

Tags: batch-file, quotes

Relatively new to batch scripts here and I have been searching everywhere for the answer only to not find anything.

Here is what I have for a batch script so far..

```
@echo off

set addtext="text to add includes spaces"

for /f "delims=" %%l in (file.txt) do (
    echo %%l %addtext% >> tmpfile.txt
)
```

I'm looking to add a line of text to every line in the file but my problem comes in with the double quotes.  I don't want the quotes to display with the text. 
 I only have the quotes there because there are spaces in the string of text that I'm looking to add to every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "addtext=text to add includes spaces"

    for /f "delims=" %%l in (file.txt) do (
        >> tmpfile.txt echo %%l %addtext%
    )
```

This should work. Just not include the quotes in the value of the variable, but use them to wrap the assignment.

In cases where the string could contain more problematic characters, this is a safer version

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "addtext=text to add includes spaces, > redirections & more problems !"

    (for %%a in ("%addtext%") do for /f "delims=" %%l in (file.txt) do (
        echo %%l %%~a
    )) >> tmpfile.txt
```

1. Quotes are not included in the value, but wraps the assignation
2. To prevent problem accessing the variable, it is wrapped in quotes, stored in a `for` replaceable parameter (`%%a`) and when requested echoed without the quotes (`%%~a`)
3. Just to get better performance (should be used also in the first code) instead of open/write/close the output file for each line (redirection for each `echo`), redirection is handled for the full `for` command.

Comment: @jeb, I have copied and pasted the code in the answer (that has delayed expansion *disabled*) and it works. To make it work as you point, the exclamation needs to be escaped on the variable definition that was what i didn't want to do. And, with delayed expansion enabled, if the source file includes `!` in its data, the output will be wrong.

Comment: You are right, I read `enabledelayedexpansion` but you wrote `enableextension` ...